# Displaylink udl in xubuntu 13.10

Tags: xorg, xubuntu, displaylink

I'm using Xubuntu Saucy Salamander (13.10).

I'm trying to connect DisplayLink wireless monitor with my Linux machine.

- My configuration is

  ```
  Nvidia GT310M
  Intel HD Graphics for 1st gen i5 processors
  [with Optimus graphics - bumblebee]
  ```
- And `uname -r` is `3.11.0-12-generic`
- And `dmesg` provides me

  ```
  [  580.150091] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
  [  580.243210] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=4047
  [  580.243216] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
  [  580.243219] usb 2-1.2: Product: WUSB Audio/Video Device
  [  580.243222] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Alereon
  [  580.243225] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 00000000-00030C
  [  580.245689] [drm] vendor descriptor length:e0 data:00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [  580.245694] [drm:udl_parse_vendor_descriptor] *ERROR* Unrecognized vendor firmware descriptor
  [  580.584559] Raw EDID:
  [  580.584567]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [  580.584569]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [  580.584572]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [  580.584574]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [  580.584576]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [  580.584578]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [  580.584581]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [  580.584583]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [  580.584588] udl 2-1.2:1.0: DVI-I-1: EDID invalid.
  [  580.585584] udl 2-1.2:1.0: fb1: udldrmfb frame buffer device
  [  580.585592] [drm] Initialized udl 0.0.1 20120220 on minor 1
  [  580.707775] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
  ```
- And `lsmod | grep udl` gives me

  ```
  udl                    24626  0 
  drm_usb                13134  1 udl
  syscopyarea            12529  1 udl
  sysfillrect            12701  1 udl
  sysimgblt              12640  1 udl
  drm_kms_helper         52651  2 udl,i915
  drm                   296739  5 udl,i915,drm_usb,drm_kms_helper
  ```
- However, `xrandr --listproviders` only gives me

  ```
  Providers: number : 1
  Provider 0: id: 0x47 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
  ```

Also, only 1 framebuffer (`fb0` for Intel) is registered.

How can I work this problem out? Thank you.

P.S. The device is based on `DL-125` chip.